# Cursor is empty but query is (supposedly) right

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've got very strange problem. 
My snippet is looking like that

```
public Wynik getData(int pomiar, int godzina) {
    Wynik wynik = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + "insulina" + " WHERE godzina = " + godzina +
            " AND cukier = " + pomiar;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)) {
        Log.i("tag", "cursor length:" + cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            String s = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor);
            Log.d("s", s);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            wynik = new Wynik
                    (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("godzina")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("insulina")),
                            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("dawka")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cialo")));
        }

        cursor.close();
        return wynik;
```

(sorry for not English convention, but it was meant to be quick, routinely project)

Whole app idea is to help my friend with his grandmother's diabetes. He would insert an result of blood sugar level test (cukier) and time of test is checked automatically (godzina).
Based on those, app should return a whole result (wynik), with required dose of insulin (dawka), type of it (insulina) and part of body from which the blood should be taken (cialo).

Database looks like this:
[image]

So for example. The blood result is 10 (it's only thing which user is inserting) and it's 7 P.M (19, by 24-hours convention - the program is giving the closest hour of test, so it's 18). So, the query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM insulina WHERE godzina = 18 AND cukier = 10
```

And here's my problem. The app is recognizing cursor length as 0 (it should be 1) even if my other app related to database creation (DB Browser for SQLite) is giving out my result properly with the same query
[image]

Also Android Studio says that database is sucessfully opened.

I cannot find a fault here. And I'm really confused with this problem.

Comment: Your insert code would also be helpful, also what happens on a rawQuery for the whole table (`SELECT * FROM insulina`), do you get a count above 0?

Comment: @MarkKeen When rawQuery asks for whole table, length looks okay'ish (" I/tag: cursor length:98 ")
There's no insert code for this database. It's pre-made database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query should be :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM insulina WHERE godzina = ? AND cukier = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
try (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(godzina), String.valueOf(pomiar)})) { 
//... rest of code
```

Also looks like you're using "try with resources" so the close isn't explicitly necessary.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!
I would like to ask additional question. I'm kind of beginner in Java so I want to "feel" difference.
 I can understand your code (It just gives a projection of results which I want), but why results don't show when I want to query them directly?

Comment: I think your query would have worked in older version of Android, like Jelly Bean.  However in later version of Android MUST supply the selectionArgs, and use `?` in the rawQuery for it to work.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29

Comment: That's why... I will remember about it. Thank you very much again!